# Is there a way to disable Safari Webdriver Glass Pane

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot, safaridriver

---

According to Apple's [Safari Webdriver Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/about_webdriver_for_safari), a glass pane is inserted while running automation windows to prevent interaction with the browser while it is being used for Webdriver testing. Is there a way to disable this glass pane?

### **Background info:**

The reason I want to disable this glass pane is that I have an nginx authentication popup which I want to dismiss.(Injection the authentication in the url like this -> https://username:password@restofurl.com does not even work in Safari).

**Selenium's Webdriver solution:**

`Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendkeys("whatever"); //Does not work`

So I went for a different solution which is AWT Robot which works well in Chrome but not in Safari due to Glass Pane:

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(820, 290);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
} catch(AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //Log exception
}
```

But unfortunately this method interrupts the test by interacting with the glass pane of the Safari Webdriver and therefore this is why I want to disable it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How do you call the webdriver:

This is how i call it

```
  public class Browser
{
    public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
    public static IWebDriver _webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    public static string _baseUrl = "http://web page/#/login";
    //public static string _baseUrl = "https://login Page/#/login";
    public static ISearchContext Driver { get { return _webDriver; } }

    internal static bool WaitElementIsDisplayed(By element, int timeout)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++)
        {
            if (ElementIsDisplayed(element))
            {
                return true;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(9000);
        }
        return false;            
    }
```

This page also has the following method

```
   public static void PopUp()
    {
        _webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
    }
```

which is called from the method that has the test code but not from the test Class

In your case

```
    try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(820, 290);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    xxxx.PopUp();
} catch(AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //Log exception
}
```

Comment: Using Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert(); does not work for any of its methods

Comment: "_webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();" would not work in my case and the robot is unable to interact with the browser without interrupting the automated tests because of the GlassPane I mentioned.